# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable then when converted to string TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, sqlite, search, type-conversion

I'm working on a python code snippet recorder and I'm getting a very strange and ***very annoying*** error.

I have an SQLite 3 database that I connect to and get a list from with the search function I have created (that works fine.) The result look similar to this:

`[(1, 'TEST', './data/test', 'test,testing'), (2, 'WORKS!', './data/works.snip', 'work,works')]`

Just to give you an idea of how the database works...

- The first item (the number: `1`&`2`) is the auto-generated key.
- The second, `TEST` & `WORKS!`, is/are the title of the entry.
- The third, `./data/test` & `./data/works.snip`, is a file related to the DB entry.
- And the fourth, `test,testing` & `work,works`, are keywords that allow me to search.

My problem is that when I am iterating through the response, I am getting the error(s) I mentioned in the title. Here's the code I'm using (BTW, if anyone sees a way I can improve this, ***please*** comment. I'm doing this project to learn Python and I would like to start with good practices)

```
for term in snipSearch:
        if term != ' ':
            toAdd + term
        elif term == ' ':
            search.append(toAdd)
            toAdd = ''

    for term in search:

        get_value_from_keyword(term)
        for respond in response:
            itr = int(str(respond[0]))
            itr = (itr - 1)
       ---->    itr = str(itr)       <-----
            returnedID = str(respond[itr][0])
                            # returnedID takes the value of
                            # response[0] and converts it to
                                    # a string

            returnedTitle = str(respond[itr][1])
                        # returnedTitle takes the value
                            # of response[1] and converts it
                            # to a string
            returnedText = str(respond[itr][2]) 
                            # returnedText takes the value
                            # of response[2] and converts it
                                # to a string
            returnedKeywords = str(respond[itr][3]) 
                            # returnedTitle takes the 
                            # value of response[1] and 
                            # converts it to a string

        returnedKeywords.split(',')

        print ("response from split:",
```

returnedID,returnedTitle,returnedText,returnedKeywords,"\n")

```
        cleanse(returnedKeywords)

        print ("response from cleanse:",cleansed,"\n")

        if cleansed == '':

            # Debugging 
            #print ("response is blank")
            continue
```

and the code that grabs the data from the database:

```
global response

    conn = sqlite3.connect('data/snippets.sqlite')

    with conn:

        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute('''SELECT *
                        FROM snippets 
                        WHERE keywords LIKE "%'''+ term + '%"')

        result = cursor.fetchall()
        # For debugging what's pulled from the database
        print ("result from db:",result,"\n")
        # end debugging

        result.append(result)

    response = result

    return(response)
```

If you want to see the code for the cleanse() function, I can give that, I just though it better to keep my post as short as possible while still providing detail. It just converts the string that is pulled from the dictionary/tuple values to a string without extra characters I don't want (eg. `[](),`)

When I go to run code as you see it, I get this error:

`TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str`

however, when I remove the line marked with the arrows it gives me this error:

`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

What is going on? This is most perturbing and I really want to continue on with this project, but I can't until this is solved :(.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Full trace of the 2nd error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snippets.py", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "snippets.py", line 32, in main
    menu()
  File "snippets.py", line 199, in menu
    search()
  File "snippets.py", line 59, in search
    returnedID = str(respond[itr][0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: First, please fix your indentation. As pasted it gives errors, and in at least one place it's ambiguous which of two possibilities you mean.

Comment: Can you give us the full traceback of the *second* error please? The first is clear and you know how to fix that one. The second error has nothing to do with `itr`, but with the *second* index you are using.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just edited

Comment: As a side note, why would you do `int(str(respond[0]))`? You've got an integer, why turn it into a string so you can turn it back into an integer?

Comment: @abarnert Not exactly sure... I just wasn't thinking. Thanks for the pointer! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
returnedID = str(respond[itr][0])
```

According to your question, `response` looks like this:

```
[(1, 'TEST', './data/test', 'test,testing'), (2, 'WORKS!', './data/works.snip', 'work,works')]
```

Therefore, each `respond` in `response` looks like this:

```
(1, 'TEST', './data/test', 'test,testing')
```

Since `itr` is ultimately `int(respond[0]) - 1`, it's the number `0`.

So `respond[itr]` is `1`.

And then `respond[itr][0]` is `1[0]`, which makes no sense—you'd expect some kind of error saying you can't index integers like sequences, and that's exactly what you get.

---

Changing `itr` into a string doesn't do any good. `respond[0]` is perfectly fine; changing it to `respond["0"]` just raises an exception before you can even get anywhere.

In general, when you have an error on a complex expression, don't just change random things to see what happens—break up the expression into parts to see which part causes the error (here, it was the *second* indexing, not the first one as you'd thought), and print out the intermediate values. For example, to debug `returnedID = str(respond[itr][0])`, turn it into this:

```
thingy = respond[itr]
returned_id_as_int = thingy[0]
returned_id = str(returned_id_as_int)
```

Now you'll see exactly where it goes wrong. And if you add in some `print`s (printing out the various values and/or their `repr`s and/or their `type`s) it will become obvious that one is not what you expect it to be. (Plus, if you can't figure it out yourself, forcing you to give a *name* to each of these things would make it much easier for someone else helping to debug your code to know what they're supposed to be.)

---

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what you actually *wanted* to do here, so I can't explain how to fix it. Maybe you *really* wanted `response[itr]`, not `respond[itr]`? But if your answers are always ordered in the way you show, `response[itr]` is always the same thing as `respond`—and if they're *not* ordered in that way, `response[itr]` is almost certainly arbitrary and useless. Maybe you just wanted `respond[0]`? But then what are you even trying to do with `itr` in the first place?

Comment: I am working on editing the answer with the code (I tweaked it). However, it is now throwing a Generator Exit thingy when I try I to branch to the search function...Grrr. Why can't programming work like it should... I will post the tweaked code once I get it working again. Uggh. Debugging.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: If you have a followup that requires a bunch of new code to demonstrate, don't modify this question, post a new question. Also, next time, try to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) rather than just a big hunk of code, most of which is irrelevant, and which can't even be run without your database.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: Anyway, if you're not writing your own generator functions (which you're not—no `yield` anywhere in your code), the only time you're likely to see `GeneratorExit` is in the `RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit` error you get from some generators if you explicitly call `close` on them and then try to `next` or iterate them afterward.

Comment: Sorry. Will definitely do that next time. As for the generators, I was working on adding in a generator, so that might be causing this new issue. Will create a SSCCE and swap my code for it.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: If you're having a completely different problem building a generator function, don't swap in that problem's SSCCE with the code for _this_ problem; create a new question and post it there.

Comment: Yeah.That's what I meant. I meant I would make an SSCCE of the current code and then update my question with that,

Comment: Hmmm. Just looking over my current code and I realized it is ***WAY*** too complicated. I'm going to re-write and accept yours as answer. Thanks for the help! I'm hoping I will end up with clearer, simpler code. Your comments and answer helped me quite a lot. Thanks!